# Symfony2: controller results in two responses

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a controller action that results in two responses.  The SwiftMailer uses the `kernel.terminate` event to accomplish this.  I can build an event listener for the event but I don't know how to tell it what I want it to do.  I know what it takes to create and download a pdf file, but how will the listener know when to do it?

#### Edit:

The "tell it" is [found here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955373/symfony2-why-is-the-request-passed-to-a-kernel-terminate-eventlistener-affected) by doing this:

```
    if ($nextAction) {
        $request->attributes->set('household_id', $id);
    }
```

But it is not at all clear how to get the event listener to do all of this (copied from a controller, but for the first line):

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
$household = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:Household')->find($id);
$fname = $household->getHead()->getFname();
$sname = $household->getHead()->getSname();
$filename = $sname . $fname . 'card.pdf';
$stylesheetXml = $this->renderView('ManaClientBundle:Test:pdfstyle.xml.twig', array());

$facade = $this->get('ps_pdf.facade');
$response = new Response();

$this->render('ManaClientBundle:Test:card.pdf.twig', array(
    'household' => $household,
    'date' => date_create(),
        ), $response);
$xml = $response->getContent();
$content = $facade->render($xml, $stylesheetXml);
header('content-type:application/pdf;' .
        'Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=' . $filename);
echo $content;
```

#### Form includes:

```
->add('save', 'submit')
->add('saveCreate', 'submit')
```

#### Controller includes:

```
$nextAction = $form->get('saveCreate')->isClicked();
if ($nextAction) {
// tell event to create and download a pdf file using $id
}
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('household_show', array('id' => $id)));
```

#### service:

```
  listener.pdfresponse:
    class: Mana\ClientBundle\EventListener\PdfListenerSubscriber
    arguments: [ @service_container ]
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate, method: onKernelTerminate }
```

#### Listener

```
namespace Mana\ClientBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\PostResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class PdfListenerSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

     private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event) {
        //create and download pdf file
    }

    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::TERMINATE => 'onKernelTerminate');
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Two responses mean two HTTP response header which means two HTTP requests. I don't think it's possible to send two response headers for one request. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ThomasPotaire: I'm beginning to think it's not possible myself.  I'd hoped to add a button to a form that would both add a record and create a PDF with data from that record.  I noticed that while in the terminate listener the originating response was not terminated.  This tells me that two responses are not possible.  Consider the question abandoned, unless someone knows how it can be done!  For now I'm doing the redirect and adding a button there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two responses to an HTTP request would never be possible - once the first request has been responded to, the connection is dropped by the web server so there would be nowhere for the second response to be sent.